# ng-bind to value returned by promise resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have angular service working with db, directive using method of this service and view where I need to show the value I get from db. I stuck on the moment where I need to bind value to view, first I tried to do it with controller (service->controller->view), but I couldn't bind value from view to controller one and realized that for asynchronously assigned value I need directive and its link function, I moved element into directive and tried to do it from there, but still no luck. So, I've got 2 questions:

Is my way of implementing this "AngularJS way"?

And if it is, how can I bind this value to view at last?

Here is the code (part of it, cropped for question):

**Service:**

```
var purchaseHistoryService = function ($q) {

    this.getUserPurchases = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Parse.Cloud.run('getUserPurchases').then(function(res) {
            var purchases = [];

            // take only part we need from purchase objects
            if(res) {
                res.forEach(function (purchase) {
                    purchases.push(purchase.attributes);
                });
            }
            return deferred.resolve(purchases);
        }, function(err) {
            return deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
};

module.exports = purchaseHistoryService;
```

**Directive:**

```
var purchaseHistoryTable = function (purchaseHistoryService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope) {

            scope.purchases = purchaseHistoryService.getUserPurchases().then(function(res) {
                console.log(res); // gives expected result, array of objects
                return res;
            }, function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "purchaseHistoryTable"
    };
};

module.exports = purchaseHistoryTable;
```

**View:**

```
.table--purchase-history
.table_cell-content_header--purchase-history(ng-bind="purchases") // check binding here, got '[object Object]'
.table_row--purchase-history(ng-repeat="purchase in purchases")
    .table_cell--purchase-history-big
        .table_cell-content--bought-packs
            .table_cell-content_header--purchase-history(ng-bind="purchase.totalPrice")
        .ver-line--purchase-history
```

Investigating issue I've found out that if I change directive like that:

```
var purchaseHistoryTable = function (purchaseHistoryService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.purchases = 'example';
        },
        templateUrl: "purchaseHistoryTable"
    };
};

module.exports = purchaseHistoryTable;
```

I've got 'example' in my view, which is ok, but when I add assigning to promise resolve value back, I've got `[object Object]` even if change return of resolve function to `return 'example';`

And questions again:

Is my way of implementing this "AngularJS way"?

And if it is, how can I bind this value to view at last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite your link function like this :

```
link: function (scope) {
       purchaseHistoryService.getUserPurchases().then(function(res) {
            console.log(res); // gives expected result, array of objects
            scope.purchases = res;// <--- HERE COPY IN THE THEN
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    },
```

Comment: wow, you're just a wizard, I've lost so much time because of it, thank you very much

Comment: by the way, why `return` with assignment wasn't working?

Comment: I'd never thought that problem was there

Comment: it's because `then` doesn't return what you return a the callback. It's return a sub promise from which you'll get as `res` what you return if you do another `then`. This is how you can chain `then` calls. It's normal since your function will get executed asynchronously.